# Regarding FB Access token

Tags: facebook

when i working with the FB (through PHP SDK).i am getting the below error frequently.

"Uncaught Exception: 190: Invalid OAuth access token signature."

Is anybody knows about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take your token you are sending in that API call that errors and lint it at: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint .  Let us know how that goes.